# Latest apache karaf camel (v3.21.2) is vulnerable to snakeyaml for CVE-2022-1471

Tags: java, apache-camel, apache-karaf, snakeyaml, apache-karaf-feature

Snakeyaml prior to v2.0 is vulnerable to **CVE-2022-1471**.

Latest Apache karaf camel is still using a vulnerable version of snakeyaml. See
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/3.21.2
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/camel/karaf/apache-camel/3.21.2/apache-camel-3.21.2-features.xml

Since camel is using snakeyaml across multiple karaf features, it's difficult to hard-code fix and might be troublesome to maintain as well.

Currently used

- camel version - 3.20.0
- apache karaf - 4.4.3
- Java - 17

Any idea of how we can fix this or update on when camel is going to provide a fix for this vulnerability?

Comment: 1). snakeyaml 1.33 is the last 1.x version and switching to 2.x (especially from OSGi perspective) is risky.

2). https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-1471 says that this CVE "is awaiting reanalysis"

3). "Deserializing yaml content provided by an attacker" is a problem when you expose unauthenticated endpoint that consumes all the YAML out there. YAML is more often used as configuration, so it's more about "if you give an attacker write permissions to config files" kind of CVE.

4) I'm not a security expert, but I live with 1.33 without problems (knowing about file permissions)

Comment: That's correct and also the reason we lived with it for so long.

Comment: Although for removing the vulnerability, we upgraded camel to latest v3.21.2 (which brings latest cxf having snakeyaml v2.0) and manually excluded the features from camel which were using snakeyaml v1.33. 


This help for now as we have excluded the vulnerable version by excluding certain feature which we don't need. But I believe it would be good if camel also provides a update with latest snakeyaml.